# How to test for a keypress or continue in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a basic powershell function that works as a spambot.

```sh
function Start-Spambot{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="The text you wish to spam.")]
        [string]$text,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="How many milliseconds between messages.")]
        [decimal]$speed,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="The tota ammout you want to spam.")]
        [decimal]$number
        )
    $count = $number
    Invoke-BalloonTip -Message "You have 3 seconds before the program starts spamming." -Title "Start-Spambot $text $speed $number"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    while ($count -gt 0){
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$text")
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $speed
        $count -= 1
    }
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$text")
    Invoke-BalloonTip -Message "$text has been typed $number times." -Title "Start-Spambot $text $speed $number"
}
```

The thing i want to add is a kill switch in the while loop. If you press 'esc' for example the script should break the while loop and continue as normal. (invoke-balloontip will make a popup in the bottem right). I have looked at a bunch and googled for hours but they all are just looking to go if the key is pressed and not the other way arround.

Any of you have a simple script or function for this?

Note:
(All of you who are complaining i dont have the code that i tried. Why would i save the things that dont work?)
Edit:
If possible it should work outside of the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more searching i finaly found this method:

```sh
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore

1..10000000 | ForEach-Object {
    "I am at $_"
    $isDown = [Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown([System.Windows.Input.Key]::LeftShift)
    if ($isDown){
    Write-Warning "ABORTED!!"
    break
    }
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 10
}
```

Edit:
It wont work in the ise wich is kinda anoying

Comment: Nicely done; to spell it out: your solution detects keypresses system-wide, _irrespective of which window has the focus_.
By contrast, `[Console]::KeyAvailable` only detects keypresses in the console window in which the PowerShell code runs.